# Trying to lock resoltution of DIV in bootstrap to specific resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a remote display server that can generate slide shows from pictures you give it. Since it will drive a variety of displays it needs to lock the resolution of certain elements that will display full screen on the display side. I can lock the width, but the height refuses to lock in with everything I try. Here is some code that pulls images of various aspect ratios that illustrate the problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <title>A Website: display page</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--My styles sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css">
    <!-- My Java Scripts -->
    <script src="/static/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Script from server for moment text generator -->
    <script src="/static/scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index">A website</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      
        
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/admin_query">Query All Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin_add_user">Add User</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin_edit_users">Edit Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/group">Groups Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin_kiosk">Kiosk Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin_display">Display Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/user/snyder">Your Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>  
  </nav>
  


<div class="full-screen-scroller" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; background-color: powderblue;">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      
      
      
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      
      
      
      
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      
      
      
      
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      
      
      
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      
      
        
        <div class="item active">
          <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Boeing_B-29_Superfortress_Bockscar_USAF.jpg" alt="Bockscar!">
          <div class="carousel-caption"><h3>Bockscar!</h3></div>
        </div>
        
        
      
        
        <div class="item">
          <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/gallery/TESLA-MOTORS-Model-S-4693_78.jpg" alt="Tesla!">
          <div class="carousel-caption"><h3>Tesla!</h3></div>
        </div>
        
        
      
        
        <div class="item">
          <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 100%" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/sleepyhollow/sleepyhollow1709/sleepyhollow170900002/85803845-african-giraffe-portrait-with-blue-sky-and-green-yellow-vegetation-background-.jpg" alt="Giraffe!">
          <div class="carousel-caption"><h3>Giraffe!</h3></div>
        </div>
        
        
      
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to "lock" heights and widths if you use relative units, like percent. Have you tried using `max-height` and `max-width` with pixel measurements?

Comment: I tried max-height with percent and it didn't work. Thanks for pointing out the max-height with pixels. Works great.